# Dev redirects to prod on every URL

Tags: redirection

I've got a dev version of a production site that seems complete and responsive, but when I navigate to that site in my browser it takes me to the prod site.

I have grepped every `.htaccess` file on the site and there is no reference to the prod site anywhere.

I can access any file except `index.php`, and `$request = Request::createFromGlobals();` creates a normal request. The creation of the `$reponse` causes the redirect.  If I put a `die()` in after `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` I'm still taken to the prod site. So, the building of the response, not the sending, causes the problem.

I've looked through and disabled any module that has a redirect in it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the response headers? You can get them with `curl -I`.

Comment: Something is throwing a 301, oddly

`Date: Wed, 01 Nov 2023 02:40:13 GMT`
`Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)`
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`
`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`
`Location: <http://prodsite.com>`
`X-Drupal-Route-Normalizer: 1`
`X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge`
`Content-language: en
`X-Content-Type-Option`s: nosniff`
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`
`X-Generator: Drupal 9 (https://www.drupal.org)`
`Cache-Tags: http_response node:2941 config:user.role.anonymous`
`Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private`
`X-Drupal-Cache: HIT`
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Redirects are cached in Drupal. Have you cleared the cache? Are you using a reverse proxy? And as a random one - is your site multilingual?

Comment: The response header `X-Drupal-Route-Normalizer` is from the Redirect module. So you should be able to remove the redirect by uninstalling this module or by disabling global redirects in the module settings. However, this doesn't explain that the prod domain is still present on the site even after clearing all caches.

Comment: Does your site use the [domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module?

Comment: The redirect module was the culprit.  I truncated the redirect table, pm:uninstalled the redirect module, and I'm back in business.  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: A further update is that with the redirect table truncated I could get to the home page on dev, but all links from that page still went back to prod.  The real culprit was language negotiation which was very easily fixed with the devel config editor.